# Row echelon form is continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

Let $M_{m\times n}$ the set of matrix with $m$- rows and $n$- columns. I have the following doubt:

Consider the function $f: M_{m\times n}\to M_{m\times n}$, where $f(A)$ is the row echelon form  of $A$. $f$ is continuous ? $f$ is open ?

Comment: Welcome to the site ! Please **EDIT** your post to include your attempts to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: That $f$ is not a function, yet. Row echelon form is not unique.

Comment: Is rank continuous?

Comment: The answer is no. Consider $f \circ g$, where $g$ is the continuous function $g(t) = tI$, with $I$ denoting the identity matrix

Answer (score 1):

If you mean reduced row echelon form (which is the one that is uniquely defined), then it can't be continuous or open, namely because $f(X)_{11}$ can only be $0$ or $1$ (and both values are realized for some matrix).